# Plotting the 3-dimensional solution of a 3 dimensional dynamical system

Tags: plotting, visualization

I used `NDSolve` on a group of 3 simultaneous ODEs for variables `{v[t], w[t], y[t]}`, with output `r`, consisting of 3 interpolation functions. I used `ParametricPlot` to get a 2D curve of any 2 variables, e.g. `v` and `w`, like this:

```
p2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{v[t], w[t]} /. r], {t, 0, 60}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

This gives a good 2D plot with correct axis ranges.

I want a 3D plot of the curve given by `{v[t], w[t], y[t]}`, so I used `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{v[t], w[t], y[t]} /. r], {t, 0, 60}]
```

Since the `w` and `y` coordinates have ranges ten times smaller than the `v` coordinate, I tried specifying plot ranges:

```
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{v[t], w[t], y[t]} /. r], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-80.0, 0.0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0.4}}]
```

the output is weird, no different than without specifying the plot ranges:

A long narrow rectangle,  labelled with -80,... 0, tilted about 30 degrees with left-hand end (-80) up. The other 2 axes are there but extremely short and numbering is overlaid. Inside the thin rectangle there is blue, obviously the actual 3D curve but squashed inside the rectangle.

Can anyone suggest how to obtain a correctly sized 3D plot displayPa?

Comment: Look at [`BoxRatios`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html). Namely, use for example: `ParametricPlot3D[..., BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`.